# While parsing json and viewing html source code it shows 10K lines

Tags: json, django, python-3.x

I am parsing json in Django Views with following code:

```
def xyz(request):
    url =" https://tools.vcommission.com/api/coupons.php?apikey=952d164efe86ca9ec33a1fdac8e6d0b6d4c02c92f44062bf8b646ad04ebf8cdc "
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    data1 = json.loads(response.read())
    context = {"data1": data1}
    template = 'coupons/store/myntra.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Now I am using this code in my template file

```
 {% for item in data1 %}
     {% if item.offer_id == "1022" %}
         {{ item.coupon_title }} <br>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

All code is working fine but when I view my template html source code it is more than 10K lines. 
It's taking more time to load.
Please suggest some ways.

Comment: The [pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/pagination/) is the 1st thing I thought of.

Comment: The result of that code is only 20 fields, so I don't want to use pagination there. Thanks for reply.